# Specifying a custom handle on jQuery UI's resizeable()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Please see the [following JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYNNg/).

I can get the `resizeable()` to work without a custom handler, but as soon as I specify the custom handler, it doesn't seem to want to resize the box -- despite triggering the start of the resizing process as denoted by the `console.log('Begin');`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in jQuery UI.  Looks like it has been around since 1.7 and has a milestone to be fixed by 2.0.

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4310